# newlines in a bash variable (grep output)

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have an assignment where I have to put every occurence of a word starting with an l into the Variable FOO, with a new line starting after every word.

So I used `grep -i -w -o "l[A-Z]*" lipsum.txt` which Outputs

> Lorem
>
> labore
>
> laboris
>
> laborum

each in a new line. So I used `FOO=$(grep -i -w -o "l[A-Z]*" lipsum.txt)` and then used `echo $FOO` to test it, but it printed all 4 in the same line. Is this a problem with echo or is it actually like that in the variable? How do I fix it?

Comment: Quote your variable: `echo "$FOO"`. By the way: regular variables are written in lowercase by convention `foo=...` instead of `FOO=...`.

Comment: Explanation: [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)